# "Análise de edições sugeridas" com texto cortado

Tags: bug, status-pronto, layout

A parte destacada em azul na imagem abaixo parece ter algum tipo de erro CSS/HTML que impede a correta visualização da edição sugerida.

Página que contém o bug: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/X](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/), onde X é o código da edição sugerida.

[image: parte cortada em destaque]

Comment: O título da outra postagem não era claro, não tinha encontrado na busca. Seria bom melhorar o título da outra pergunta.

Comment: Tem razão, já editei o título lá.